# jsonp loop through the data

Tags: jquery, loops, jsonp

I have a webservice returning jsonp format. here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
       $.getJSON("http://api.tubeupdates.com/?method=get.status&lines=central,victoria&return=name&jsonp=?",
             function (result){
                  $.each(result.items, function(item){
                     $('body').append(item.response.lines[0].name);

             });
        }
     );

});
```

It works fine if I remove the loop but fails with the $.each loop.
Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Mauro

Comment: What does the JSON data look like?! It *kind of* matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response doesn't have an array on an `items` property, it looks like this:

```
{"response":{"lines":[{"name":"Central"},{"name":"Victoria"}]}}
```

It looks like you want to iterate the `response.lines` array, in which case you need to do this:

```
$.each(result.response.lines, function(i, item){
   $('body').append(item.name);
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Yh6S9/).

Comment: Thanks! didn't notice that 'response' wasn't an array!